# Meaning of sentence in EGA I, Section 1.7.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, translation-request, mathematical-french

In Section 1.7 of EGA I, we have the following:

> (1.7.1) Étant donné un $A$-module $M$, on appelle  support de  $M$ et on note $\text{Supp}(M)$ l'ensemble  des  idéaux  premiers  $\mathfrak{p}$  de  $A$  tels  que $M_{\mathfrak{p}} \ne 0$.   Pour  que  $M = 0$,   il  faut  et il  suffit que  $\text{Supp}(M)  = \emptyset$,  car  si  $M_{\mathfrak{p}}= 0$  pour tout $\mathfrak{p}$, l'annulateur d'un  élément  $x \in M$ ne  peut  être  contenu  dans  aucun  idéal  premier  de  $A$,  donc  est  $A$  tout  entier.

I would translate this as follows:

> Being given an $A$-module $M$, we say the {\it support} of $M$ and we write $\text{Supp}(M)$ for the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ such that $M_{\mathfrak{p}} \ne 0$. For $M = 0$, it is necessary and sufficient that $\text{Supp}(M) = \emptyset$, because if $M_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ for every $\mathfrak{p}$, the annihilator of an element $x \in M$ cannot be contained in any prime ideal of $A$, therefore $A$ is [???].

As you can see, I am stuck on the phrase "tout entier". It sounds like "completely integral", but what does this actually mean in this context?

Comment: "...therefore is equal to $A$."

Comment: "donc *l'annulateur* est A tout entier"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments by user26857 and Billy, I see now that it's just saying the annihilator must be all of $A$.